# Load two different json based on condition

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I wanted to know how to load 2 diffrent json based on condition

```
.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {   

        if (lang==1){
                $scope.myVariable = [];
            $http.get('json/data.json').success (function(data){
                $scope.myVariable = data;
            });
        }
        else if (lang==2){
            $scope.myVariable = [];
            $http.get('json/data_ar.json').success (function(data){
                $scope.myVariable = data;
            }); 

        }

    }])
```

the variable passes to lang but json not loading if lang==2

I want to load data.json if english and data_ar.json for arabic. I do this on click of anchor tag

Comment: Could you show us where the `lang` is defined?

Comment: <script>
      var lang = 1;
            $(function(){   
                $("#langtoggle").click(function(){                      
                       
                            if(lang==1){
                                 var lang=2;
                                } else if(lang==2){
                                   var lang=1;
                                }
                            
                        });
                });
            
        </script> 
 

<a id="langtoggle">change language</a>

Answer (score 1):

please  put your following code just inside any method like this:

```
.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope','$http','$rootScope','$route', function($scope, $http,$rootScope,$route) {  


        if ($rootScope.lang==1){
                $scope.myVariable = [];
            $http.get('json/data.json').success (function(data){
                $scope.myVariable = data;
            });
        }
        else if ($rootScope.lang==2){
            $scope.myVariable = [];
            $http.get('json/data_ar.json').success (function(data){
                $scope.myVariable = data;
            }); 

        }

     $scope.loadData=function(lang){
         $rootScope.lang=lang;
         $route.reload();
     }

}])
```

and html code:

```
<a ng-click="loadData(2)">arabic formate</a>
```

or you have done like this then please post full html and controller code related to that functionality so that i can see, where you have done mistake.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Unfortunately its still not working.

Comment: could you please tell me if any error are you getting?

Comment: it always load data.json even if the lang = 1 or 2. wen the user clicks the arabic button, it should reload the myCtrl controller so that it will check lang is 1 0r 2. But in my case its not reloading, pls help

Comment: could you please put html and controller code at http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview so that i can find where you are getting issue. and paste that plnkr link here

Comment: ithink your default value for lang is 1. when controller load. it takes default value. so put lang in $rootScope variable like; $rootScope.lang and inject $rootScope in controller and use If($rootScope.lang==1).

Comment: thanks for your comments. I tried this way, but it isnt working. myCtrl is called only when the link for aboutus page is clicked. and language switch is happening with another <a>, the reason myCtrl is not called again when the language link is clicked so the ar json is not loading. I was just wondering how to activate the myCtrl whenever the language link is clicked for each page.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you have defined `lang` in the HTML page. Make sure, that the definition is wrapped with an element with `ng-controller="myCtrl"` attribute.
Now use `if ($scope.lang==2)` instead of `if (lang==2)`

Answer (score 1):

You defined another `lang` variables in `lang` switching script. So change:

```
if(lang==1){ var lang=2; } else if(lang==2){ var lang=1; }
```

to:

```
if(lang==1){ lang=2; } else if(lang==2){ lang=1; }
```